# What's better to use: > or >= for optimization

Tags: javascript, php, math

I am writing a simple program where I want to compare if an integer is greater than 0

Clearly, there are two ways

```
if(x>-1){}
//or
if(x>=0)
```

Which amongst these is considered more optimized or efficient?

Comment: Neither of these do what you want (your comparison is wrong). Also, the performance between them will be negligible or non-existent.

Comment: What's wrong with `if(x<0)`?

Comment: virtually there will be no performance difference

Comment: There is no optimization here. You are thinking too much...

Comment: Typed it in wrong. Sorry about that. corrected for "greater than 0"

Comment: what is with `-0.8`? do you need only to check integers?

Answer (score 5):

Both of your comparisons are incorrect.

> I am writing a simple program where I want to compare if a value is less than 0

Then do just that, which translates to  `if(x<0)`, Everything else is fancy thinking and nothing more.

**Even the updated comparisons are invalid**

> I want to compare if an integer is greater than 0

Then it should be

```
if(x>0)
```

Both comparisons in the updated question will return true if x = 0 which makes them mismatch the desired logic.

Comment: OP updated question, now they would like a _greater than_ comparison.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If an OP can typo 2 different simple equations they really don't know what they are asking

Comment: @evolutionxbox ironically even the updated comparisons in the questions are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any discernible difference. I would stick to `>=0` just because it's slightly easier to read, but that's just my opinion.

Also if you're looking for a number that's negative, both of those if statements are backwards.

Comment: _"compare if a value is less than 0"_

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
if(x <0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is a negligible performance difference, technically your two written out how they are processed is:

```
if(x > -1){}
if(x > 0 || x == 0){}
```

x >= 0 is just short hand, and easier on the eyes. Again though, with a problem like this you are talking a nanosecond difference